# Setting GCloud SDK properties through environment variables

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to [configure properties for the Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/properties) in a non-interactive environment (specifically, a Docker container), and I'd like to use environment variables to do it (because it seems much simpler to get right and portable compared to volume-mounting config files...). However, I can't find any documentation on what the environment variables should be called, etc.

Is it possible to configure the Google Cloud SDK using environment variables, and how do I do so?

---

Clarification: For now, the only property I care about is the default project, `core/project` in [this listing](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set).

Comment: which properties exactly?

Comment: @mattb The default project.

Comment: There is a set of environment variables (`CLOUDSDK_`) that match some (all?) of the gcloud config properties. I was unable to find these documented but I'm aware of them through the `kubectl` Cloud Builder (see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/kubectl/kubectl.bash))

Comment: See this [post](https://medium.com/@nieldw/using-environment-variables-to-set-gcloud-config-9eb2da7666e7) too

Comment: @DazWilkin: The `CLOUDSDK_` set of env vars was exactly what I was looking for - and it also turned out to work for my use case!

If you put that in a proper answer, I can give you some rep for it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a set of environment variables (`CLOUDSDK_`) that match some (all?) of the gcloud config properties.

I was unable to find these documented but I'm aware of them through the [kubectl](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/kubectl) Cloud Builder (see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/kubectl/kubectl.bash)) and this [post](https://medium.com/@nieldw/using-environment-variables-to-set-gcloud-config-9eb2da7666e7)

I've submitted an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144246543) asking Google to document these (more clearly).

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/properties#setting_properties_using_environment_variables):

> You can also set properties using environment variables. Each property has a corresponding environment variable that can be used to set it. The name of the environment variable follows the CLOUDSDK_SECTION_NAME_PROPERTY_NAME pattern. For example, you can set the core/project and compute/zone properties as follows:
>
> ```
> CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=PROJECT_NAME
> CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=ZONE_NAME
> ```

---

I tried to update the accepted answer but wasn't allowed to.